# Image data fusion

Tags: matlab, python, opencv

I have three cameras separated by some distance, looking at a scene. I have calibrated them using checkerboard and I have their respective intrinsic parameters and their pose and rotation matrix, I am stuck as to how to do data/image fusion.

I think I have to do feature detection and feature matching and then do data fusion but I am not sure if I am on the right path.

Would be very helpful if anyone can point me to some answer or help me with it.

Or if I am wrong then what is the right method or steps to follow?

Would be really helpful even if someone can point to a resource or just guide. Thank you, good people

Comment: You should define data/image fusion clearly. As it is, it is difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

## What do you mean by data fusion

Here's some definitions I can think of:

1. Determine from the features in the scene the positions of the camera
2. Determine from the positions of the camera the geometry of the scene
3. Determine from the features of the scene the intrinsic parameters of the camera.

Since you say you have fully calibrated the three cameras jointly using a checkerboard, then 1 and 3 are done. That must leave 2.

## Estimating positions of features, or [structure from motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion)

To estimate the position of a feature in the world, you first define what features. All pixels? That would be called [disparity mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17620159/389599) Just a few features? That you can do with [triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_%28computer_vision%29).

Comment: I guess this is what I was looking for, thank you so much.